# PDF as byte array from WebService to SilverLight and show in new browser Tab/Window

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, silverlight, pdf

I have a Silverlight application which gets a byte[] array generated by a method from a Web Service , both (the web app and the service) are in different web hostings . The method generates a pdf as byte[] array based on the results of a query to a database in MySQL.

I need to open the PDF without having to save it to disk the computer that is running the web client application and display it in a new tab / window web browser.

The generated pdf in byte[] is returned by the web service as a means of:

```
[WebMethod]
public byte[] GenerarPdf(string idNotaria, string ot, string repertorio, string NombreReporte, string c1, string c2, string c3, string obs)
        {
        return Seguimiento.GenerarPdf( idNotaria, ot, repertorio, NombreReporte, c1, c2, c3, obs);
        }
```

In the Silverlight web application I have a button that receives the byte [ ] array by :

```
private void btnFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                busyIndicatorMain.BusyContent = "Generando archivo...";
                busyIndicatorMain.IsBusy = true;
                string nom = s.NomArchivo.Substring(0, s.NomArchivo.Length - 3);
                    Servicio.ServiceSoapClient serv = new ServiceSoapClient();
                    serv.getEscrituraCompleted += new EventHandler<getEscrituraCompletedEventArgs>(serv_getEscrituraCompleted);
                    serv.getEscrituraAsync(s.OtNumero,s.IdReg,_idUsuario);
        }

private void serv_getEscrituraCompleted(object sender, getEscrituraCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                if (e.Result != null)
                {

                    byte[] fileBytes =e.Result as byte[];
                    //Atascado aqui/Stuck here...
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error generando...","Error",MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
            }
            busyIndicatorMain.IsBusy = false;
        }
```

What or how can I do to display the pdf in a new window / browser tab? 
Do I need to create some new object, a new page?

Ideally, than the pdf to be opened from memory.

Could you guide me please? 
Thank you. (Sorry if my English is not good.)

Comment: Hi,Were you every able to find an answer to the question?